# vertx: returning final response of API only after getting response of all internal calls

Tags: async-await, vert.x

I am writing an API in vertx which requires a downstream system to be called multiple times. I want final api response to be returned only after all the downstream call are completed. but because of highly async nature of vertx, final reponse is getting returned before getting all downstream responses.

```
public void externalcall(RoutingContext routingContext) {
    map<int, some_class> map = new hashmap();
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        some_class = internalcall(i);
        map.put(i, some_class);
    }
    routingContext.response().putHeader("content-type", "application/json; 
    charset=utf-8").end(Json.encodePrettily(map));
}
```

What is the best possible way to tackle above problem in vertx?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you are correct, vert.x is async so you need to rely on futures or RX.

Using `CompletableFuture`

```
List<CompletableFuture> futuresList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    futuresList.add(internalcall(i));
}
CompletableFuture
        .allOf(futuresList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futuresList.size()]))
        .handle((res, ex) -> {
            routingContext.response().putHeader("content-type", "application/json;charset=utf-8").end(Json.encodePrettily(futuresList));
            return null;
});
```

The `handle` will only execute when all of the internal calls are done. Your return type of `internalcall` method should be `CompletableFuture`

```
public CompletableFuture<JsonObject> internalcall(int i) {
    CompletableFuture<JsonObject> promise = new CompletableFuture<>();
    someAsyncCall(i, res -> {
            if(res.succeeded()){
                promise.complete(res.result());
            }else{
                promise.completeExceptionally(new Exception(res.cause()));
            }
        });
    return promise;
}
```

You can go with RX, you will have much cleaner and smaller code.